# How do I determine the make & model of my storage devices?

Tags: hardware, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what hard disks are in the system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/how-do-i-find-out-what-hard-disks-are-in-the-system)

I'm running a CentOS 5.5 system. This system has 4 disks and a 3ware RAID controller. How can I determine the make and model of my drives?

`/proc/scsi/scsi` and `parted --list` shows the RAID controller (3ware 9650SE-4LP):

```
# cat /proc/scsi/scsi 
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: AMCC     Model: 9650SE-4LP DISK  Rev: 4.06
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05

# parted --list

Model: AMCC 9650SE-4LP DISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
```

Comment: See [How do I find out what hard disks are in the system?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/how-do-i-find-out-what-hard-disks-are-in-the-system). If there's not enough information, what's missing?

Comment: @Giles : That's enough information. I didn't see that post after multiple searches.

Comment: Having seen your answer in the other thread, I think it would actually make more sense here: you have a more specific question about a particular hardware RAID model.