# Can I see what HDD I have installed?

Tags: hard-disk, hardware

I use `lspci` for pci devices and `lsusb` to list the usb hardware devices, is there something  similar to list my SATA HDD model ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [hdparm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm) to retrieve information about your hard drives, eg.,

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

Where `I`, according to the `man` page:

```
-I     Request  identification  info  directly  from the 
drive, which is displayed in a new expanded format with considerably
 more detail than with the older -i option.
```

For SCSI drives, use [sdparm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sdparm).

Answer (score 4):

`hdparm` usually with the `-i` or `-I` options should give you rather exhaustive information.

Answer (score 4):

`smartctl -a` will even tell you the serial numbers of the disks.

Comment: `hdparm` does that too.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already accepted an answer but I thought I'd add something for posterity:

If you need to know what block devices are seen by the kernel `/sys/block/*` will have the listing. You'll have to sift through that list to filter out the virtual devices that just present to the system as block devices.

Most modern distributions will also list the devices by their path (for example, if they're SAN, which HBA and what the WWPN they're coming from, etc) if you do `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path`:

```
[root@dfletcher ~]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-path
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:2:1:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:2:1:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:2:2:0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:2:2:0-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:1a:00.0-fc-0x500601663ee0025f:0x0000000000000000 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:1a:00.0-fc-0x500601663ee0025f:0x0015000000000000 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:1a:00.0-fc-0x5006016e3ee0025f:0x0000000000000000 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:1a:00.0-fc-0x5006016e3ee0025f:0x0015000000000000 -> ../../sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:1a:00.1-fc-0x500601653ee0025f:0x0000000000000000 -> ../../sdh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:1a:00.1-fc-0x500601653ee0025f:0x0015000000000000 -> ../../sdi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:1a:00.1-fc-0x5006016d3ee0025f:0x0000000000000000 -> ../../sdj
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 27 17:17 pci-0000:1a:00.1-fc-0x5006016d3ee0025f:0x0015000000000000 -> ../../sdk
[root@dfletcher ~]#
```

In the last line `pci-0000:1a:00.1-fc-0x5006016d3ee0025f:0x001500000000000` can be read left to right as: coming off the `pci` bus, from device at PCI address `1a:00.1`,  fibre channel protocol(`fc`), with the remote WWPN of `0x5006016d3ee0025f`. The last number is a LUN id that the HBA has assigned to that LUN, but I've never found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `hdparm` and can't install it then you can try `dmesg | grep -i ata` to obtain some information about your hard disks.