# How does Dolphin discover the disks to mount?

Tags: mount, kde, automounting, dolphin

After I ran Dolphin, I noticed that two new mounts, like `dev/sda1` for windows NTFS and `dev/sdd1` have appeared in my system. Where are they defined? It is not surprise that I could not find them in `/etc/fstab`.

It is curious to know particularly if I do not lose these devices if install new version of Fedora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dolphin makes use of the [Solid](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/solid/html/namespaceSolid.html) namespace to detect devices. As long as you have the correct drivers installed for your disks, they should still be discovered even after an upgrade to a new version of Fedora. You can use `lscpi` to check the drivers or have a look at [this StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41819/177175) for some other tips. Though as far as I know, drivers aren't typically dropped unless they are for older hardware that's no longer relevant. `/etc/fstab` just shows devices that have been set to be mounted automatically at boot time though. You can get a more complete list of available devices by running `fdisk -l` with elevated privileges (either via root or sudo) if you have it. Otherwise, I would take a look at [this StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4563/177175) for some other options to check available disks.